# Automaticity resolving dependency for code analysis

Tags: java, maven, code-analysis, static-analysis, inria-spoon

I have simple `scala` code with `Spoon` library:

```
class ExtractCodeDataTest extends FlatSpec {


  it should "Run and not be empty" in{

    val l = new Launcher()
    l.addInputResource("./testData/owasp-security-logging")

    l.buildModel()

    val factory = l.getFactory
    val allClass = factory.Class().getAll(true)

    println(allClass)
  }

}
```

I had cloned open source project from github but I can't compile it.

```
The import org.junit cannot be resolved at /home/user/IdeaProjects/testSearch/testData/owasp-security-logging/owasp-security-logging-logback/src/test/java/org/owasp/security/logging/filter/SecurityMarkerFilterTest.java:3
spoon.compiler.ModelBuildingException: The import org.junit cannot be resolved at /home/user/IdeaProjects/testSearch/testData/owasp-security-logging/owasp-security-logging-logback/src/test/java/org/owasp/security/logging/filter/SecurityMarkerFilterTest.java:3
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.report(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:583)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.reportProblems(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:564)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.build(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:120)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.build(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:101)
```

I can't find any way for automaticity resolving dependency? How fix them for general projects- not only this particular one?

Answer (score 1):

Spoon can be used in two different modes:

1. with full classpath
2. in "no-classpath mode"

With the first mode, you have to provide to Spoon the whole classpath necessary to analyze the project for example in using the arguments `--source-classpath` in command line, or by using `launcher.getEnvironment().setSourceClasspath(String[])`. In this mode you'll have a maximum of information to analyze your code.

With the second mode, Spoon will only analyze the given source code without exploiting information from libraries. You won't be able to get all the information of classes from external libraries, or to compile the code but still you can analyze the code source of the project. You can use this mode by setting `launcher.getEnvironement().setNoClasspath(true)`.

Please note that an issue is opened on Spoon to be able to automatically analyze a Maven project, in considering the whole dependencies given in the pom.xml, see: https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/issues/1396.